# why I can't vote up for myself BUT vote down?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, voting

why I can't vote up to myself BUT vote down ?
I have a try then my question is voted down . WHY?

Comment: You can't vote yourself down.

Comment: Probably someone downvoted your post the same moment when you tried to upvote it.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely situation is that someone else downvoted you as you were attempting to upvote yourself.

- You gain the ability to upvote people at a reptutation of 15 (you
  have 6, you can't cast votes on anybody currently)
- You gain the ability to downvote people at 125 rep (which 6 isn't
  even close)
- And you will never gain the ability to vote on your own
  questions/answers/comments

Comment: Just for reference, you can cast closevotes, reopen votes, and delete votes on your posts with the correct amount of rep.

Comment: @obsessiveSSO, that hardly applies to him (he has 6 rep)